# How can I acquire the basic function type from an std::function?

Tags: c++, function, tr1, type-traits

I have a lot of classes with a typedef of `std::function<void(PARAMS)>` where PARAMS is specific to each class. I need to specialize based on the number of parameters and the first parameter's type. I'd like to use `boost::function_traits` for this, but in order to use it, I need to have the raw function type of the `std::function` in question.

For example, given `std::function<void(int,int)>`, I want to retrieve `void(int,int)`.

Is there any way to extract the native type in a portable manner? As a side note, I do not have access to C++11 features.

Comment: `std::function` is new in C++11, so how are you not gonna use it?

Comment: `std::function` is part of TR1. I omitted the tr1 namespace. Being so pedantic doesn't benefit anyone.

Comment: then please tell us which C++11 features you don't have access to, perhaps you have it already in TR1

Comment: @dauphic: He isn't being pedantic, he just points out the appearent confusion in your question. You claim to not have C++11 available, yet you want to reason about C++11 stuff (if you would use tr1, then you would surely have told  us you use std::tr1::function, so this is confusing). Additionally, most people asking questions and saying "no C++11" mean "only C++03"

Comment: What's the difference between TR1 and C++11's implementations of `std::function`, aside from a missing namespace?

Comment: @dauphic: `std::function` is a variadic template, so when it is moved to the `std` namespace, it would be upgraded to a variadic template (provided your compiler supports that feature).

Comment: @dauphic: I couldn't find a general question about it here on SO, if you ask for general changes to TR1 when it got absorbed by C++11, I'll upvote.

Comment: Exactly. Whether I'm using `std::function` or `std::tr1::function` has absolutely no bearing on my question. Both have exactly the same behavior, as far as my question is concerned. It's pure pedantry and adds absolutely nothing to the conversation.

Comment: @dauphic No pedantry was intended. Sorry if my comment was too curt and came across like that.

Comment: @JesseGood, your comment seems rather MSVC-specific. `std::tr1::function` might be a variadic template too (provided your compiler supports that feature). Just because a certain compiler doesn't support variadic templates even in C++11 doesn't mean other compilers have to use the same kluges to emulate variadic templates. In other words, for some implementations there's not much difference except for the different namespace.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I didn't know that. I mainly based my comment off of [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#C.2B.2B_standard_library_changes) which says: `However, as TR1 features were brought into the C++11 standard library, they were upgraded where appropriate with C++11 language features that were not available in the initial TR1 version`. Perhaps that quote was incorrect?

Comment: @JesseGood, it's not incorrect, as the TR1 classes were updated to support e.g. rvalue references and perfect forwarding, but other features such as variadic templates have been present in GCC [since 2007](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/variadic-templates), long before the TR1 components were included in the draft standard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the function type, you can use partial specialization:

```
template <typename T>
struct Detect;

template <typename F>
struct Detect<std::function<F>> {
  typedef F Result;
};
```

Now when you get an unknown `std::function<?>` type `T`, you just use

```
typename Detect<T>::Result
```

(you might want do define `Result` as `F *`, as some contexts (e.g., field types) only allow pointer-to-function, and not bare function types.

Edit:

To specialize on the number of arguments and the type of the first one, you would need either C++11 variadic templates

```
template <typename T>
struct Detect;

template <typename R, typename A, typename... As>
struct Detect<std::function<R(A,As...)>> {
  static constexpr auto numargs = 1 + sizeof...(As);
  typedef R Result;
  typedef A FirstArg;
};
```

or to code the equivalent of the above, using a separate specialization for each possible number of arguments:

```
template <typename R, typename A1>
struct Detect<std::function<R(A1)>> {
  enum { numargs = 1 };
  typedef R Result;
  typedef A1 FirstArg;
};

template <typename R, typename A1, typename A2>
struct Detect<std::function<R(A1,A2)>> {
  enum { numargs = 2 };
  ...
};

...
```

Comment: `typedef std::tuple<Args...> parameter_types; static std::size_t const num_parameters = sizeof...(Args);`

Answer (score 3):

`std::function` contains `result_type`, `argument_type` for unary functions, and `first_argument_type` and `second_argument_type` for binary functions. You can extract these. For `n-ary` functions defined with variadic templates, I don't think there is a `std::tuple` containing all the arguments.

If you want your own traits class:

```
template<typename Fun>
struct function_traits;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<std::function<R(Args...)>
{
    typedef R return_type;
    typedef std::tuple<Args...> arguments_type;
};
```

Comment: you seem to have a minor mistake here -- the non-specialized declaration of `function_traits` has multiple arguments, instead of just one (you supply it with an `std::function<...>`; this works "by accident", with `Args` always being empty :)

Comment: still wrong (and now it won't even compile) -- just use `template <typename> class function_traits;`; also, make it a struct, or add `public:` before the extracted traits! :)

Comment: @GrzegorzHerman Summertime and the temperature is cooking my brain :-)

Comment: here it's almost midnight, so the temperatures are much better :)

Comment: Using `Args&&` in the partial spec makes things go wildly wrong, by-value parameters become rvalue refs. Don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be simple enough to create a metafunction to extract the `T` in the `boost::function<T>`

```
template<typename T>
struct func_extractor

template<typename T>
struct func_extractor<boost::function<T> >
{
   typedef T type;
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::function<void(int, int)> func_type1; 
    typedef func_extractor<func_type1>::type extracted_type;
    typedef boost::function<extracted_type> func_type2;
    std::cout << boost::is_same<func_type1, func_type2>::value << std::endl;
}
```